# Посветлу, по светлу или по-светлу — как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, орфоэпия, слитно-раздельно-дефис

*Здесь же,на объездной, не выбираясь из кунгов, встали на ночлег – судя по карте, дальше их ждала Вычегда, а переправляться через реку куда удобнее **посветлу.***
[**Д. Шабалов. Право на жизнь**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=IfZhAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT257&lpg=PT257&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83&source=bl&ots=tZsGNJSzf3&sig=gRZMZJxWJyBqXsizuowiRfpWqo0&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizyuPg_7HYAhUnApoKHWoxAr04ChDoAQgxMAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83&f=false)

*Всё первую половину дня они прошли почти без остановки, чтобы преодолеть **по светлу** большую часть пути.*
[**И. Ивко. Фиолетовый дракон**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=lgrUDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT7&lpg=PT7&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83&source=bl&ots=zUOVASOxnn&sig=ZG_s5rgK8QZDmFHlFAWm3ZFJdU4&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisuImfgLLYAhWmIpoKHTBbDLcQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83&f=false)

*– Ну, наконец-то! Лететь далеко, возвращаться уже **по-светлу** придется, – пробурчал летчик.*
[**Ю. Корчевский. «Качай маятник»! Особист из будущего (сборник)**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=5UCJCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT543&lpg=PT543&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83&source=bl&ots=Zog8nd0xDh&sig=gosPAg_TxekqH_xOBjFZLqjayvc&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixyPin-7HYAhWjDpoKHa91AGUQ6AEITTAG#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83&f=false)

В словарях это слово не обнаружилось (а ведь употребляется, и довольно часто!).
Хотелось бы понять: как правильно ***написать*** и правильно ***сказать***?
(В нашей семье говорят с ударением на **у**.)

Answer (score 2):

> Хотелось бы понять: как правильно написать и правильно сказать?
>   (В нашей семье говорят с ударением на у.)

Я могу произнести это слово только с ударением на первый слог. По поводу как написать: долго не мог найти убедительный источник, пока не догадался, что это слово образовано по аналогии со словом "потемну", которое зафиксировано в словарях как разговорное. Это сузило поиск, и тогда уже попался [заслуживающий доверия источник](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=424lAAAAMAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%83&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%83&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIlqDdl7LYAhUKaVAKHZejDfEQ6AEIKjAB).

Comment: _Я могу произнести это слово только с ударением на первый слог._ А **мы**  ориентировались на ПОУТРУ́ (см.https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/176762 и https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/223318).

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Спасибо, очень интересное наблюдение. Для меня здесь тоже "пОутру". Но мои ударения точно не могут служить для кого-то образцом — уж очень в них намешано местных диалектов. Просто сообщаю как есть :)

Comment: Не могу представить, как на последний слог можно делать ударение в "посветлу". По-моему, на приставку, предлог в большинстве случаев естественней звучит.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Но пОсветлу — я тоже не могу произнести иначе.

Comment: А с *поутру* сложнее: "И сам не знает поутрУ//куда поедет ввечеру." (Пушкин) Но: "Спой мне песню, как девица. За водой поУтру шла." (Тот же Пушкин), "Небо и земля – вот наша доля!// Нам дали вольную пОутру в поле." (Гребенщиков) – 113